# How can I be sure that video hardware decoding is happening?

Tags: video, hardware, cpu, vaapi

I have a skylake CPU that can do hardware decoding of many codecs except 10bit H265. I have a lot of videos that have been encoded in 8bit H265. Playing those videos in windows shows no CPU usage at all. However, I've tried several video players on Ubuntu, from VLC to Kodi, and the same video consumed on average about 10% CPU, even after explicitly choosing vaapi. So, how can I be sure that hardware decoding is happening ?

Comment: Please install `inxi` and then post the output of `inxi -F` by editing your question.